# Bifurcation package like AUTO?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, packages

I was wondering if there is any available continuation and bifurcation analysis package for Mathematica. I'm looking for something like [AUTO](http://indy.cs.concordia.ca/auto/). I've seen there is already a Matlab version of the software.

Comment: I don't know if there is any package but there are demonstrations for different types of bifurcations on http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/

Answer (score 5):

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/149/ This looks like a solution.  Its called dynpac4.

An updated version is available at http://www2.me.rochester.edu/~clark/dynpac.html

Comment: Interesting find!  That version is quite old, from the year 2000 when Mathematica `$VersionNumber==4.0`.  There's an updated version of the package available [here](http://www2.me.rochester.edu/~clark/dynpac.html).  I'll have a look and see what continuation and bifurcation functions it has.

Comment: The package is a product of its time ("it often looks like the FORTRAN I wrote for 30 years" as per the introduction :-), but there are many great pedagogical examples of dynamical systems in there.  Something like this needs to be updated!  Unfortunately it doesn't look like there are functions for continuing an equilibrium or detecting bifurcations like AUTO or CONTENT can.

Comment: @ChrisK I tried a few examples and they all worked, which is somewhat unusual for such an old package. Ironically, this is very likely because the author went against convention and used *all lowercase* names. These days the biggest menace to package compatibility is that new versions of Mathematica indiscriminately add lots of new names into the system namespace, which pretty much guarantees that some packages will break.